# How to get subset of string within same list

Tags: python-3.x

I have one list

```
a = ['find old', 'find old mails', 'finding', 'find your pc', 'find your pc s ip', 'find your pc s ip address']
```

i want to remove SUBSET STRING from list which will give me result as

```
['find old mails', 'finding', 'find your pc s ip address']
```

Test Code

```
a = ['find old', 'find old mails', 'finding', 'find your pc', 'find your pc s ip', 'find your pc s ip address']
b = len(a)
def is_sub(sub, lst):
    ln = len(sub)
    return any(lst[i: i + ln] == sub for i in range(len(sub) - ln + 1))

# print(is_sub(a[0],a[2]))
for i in range(b-1):
    for j in range(i+1,b):
        if is_sub(a[i],a[j]):
            index = a.index(a[i])
            a.remove(a[index])
            break
    b = len(a)

print(a)
```

I am getting output as

```
['find old mails', 'finding', 'find your pc s ip', 'find your pc s ip address']
```

and expected output

```
['find old mails', 'finding', 'find your pc s ip address']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By making a few alterations to your substring checking function (specifically using `in` to check for substrings) and using a list comprehension, you can achieve the desired result:

```
def is_sub(item, lst):
    """Check whether an item is a substring of other items in a list."""
    return any([item in i for i in [i for i in lst if i != item]])

output = [i for i in a if not is_sub(i, a)]
```

```
['find old mails', 'finding', 'find your pc s ip address']
```

Comment: This was slick!

Comment: Great answer, although why use list comprehensions? Generators would be way more efficient especially for longer lists. Like this: `any(item in i for i in (i for i in lst if i != item))`

Comment: I agree, if you started getting long lists or parsing logs that would be the preferred route. However for the OP's problem as described performance was not the principal concern, and the generator aspect could be a confusion point for some less familiar with python which may come across the question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `in` keyword?

```
a = ['find old', 'find old mails', 'finding', 'find your pc', 'find your pc s ip', 'find your pc s ip address']
new = []
f = 0
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    f=0
    for j in range(0, len(a)):
        if a[i] in a[j] and not i==j:
            f=1
            break;
    if f==0: new.append(a[i])
print(new)
```

This gives -

```
['find old mails', 'finding', 'find your pc s ip address']
```